# Can I write FileWriter and bufferedwriter in a same class in Java?

Tags: java, filewriter, bufferedwriter

Here is the code, in which I'm trying to write using Filewriter. This is working fine.

```
File f2 = new File("Path");
f2.createNewFile();
FileWriter writing = new FileWriter(f2);    
writing.write("i'm into you , i'm into you");   
writing.flush();
```

In the following code, I'm trying to write using bufferedwriter. This is not adding any text into the same file. For different file, it is working.

```
BufferedWriter buffwrite = new BufferedWriter(writing);     buffwrite.write("java");    
writing.flush();
```

Comment: try `buffwrite.flush()` you are flushing the FileWriter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should `close` the resources your opened: `FileWriter writing` and `BufferedWriter buffwrite`. This ([JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html#close()))

> Flushes the stream. If the stream has saved any characters from the
>   various write() methods in a buffer, write them immediately to their
>   intended destination. Then, if that destination is another character
>   or byte stream, flush it. Thus one flush() invocation will flush all
>   the buffers in a chain of Writers and OutputStreams.

The right way is to use the [try-resource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement. This will tale care to close opened resources.

Or use the `java.nio.file.Files.write` methods which will do the resource handling.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, definitely you can write both in same class. 
Your code is not adding any text into the same file because you are Flushing out FileWriter before BufferedWriter. I just edited your code as below and it worked fine.

```
File f2 = new File("Path");
f2.createNewFile();
FileWriter writing = new FileWriter(f2);  
writing.write("i'm into you , i'm into you");

BufferedWriter buffwrite = new BufferedWriter(writing); 
buffwrite.write("java"); 

buffwrite.flush();//flush BufferedWriter first followed by FileWriter
writing.flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

These IO related classes are designed based on decorator pattern.

If you refer to the `BufferedWriter` class javadoc, you'd find a constructor that takes a `Writer` type object. `Writer` is an abstract class which is extended by `FileWriter` among other classes. Pass your `FileWriter` object in the constructor and then call the `write (...)` and `flush` methods of `BufferedWriter`.

All IO classes work in this pattern.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes** you can write.Please checkout the below usecases for writing file in java using FileWriter, BufferedWriter, FileOutputStream and Files in java.

```
package com.journaldev.files;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class WriteFile {

    /**
     * This class shows how to write file in java
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String data = "I will write this String to File in Java";
        int noOfLines = 10000;
        writeUsingFileWriter(data);

        writeUsingBufferedWriter(data, noOfLines);

        writeUsingFiles(data);

        writeUsingOutputStream(data);
        System.out.println("DONE");
    }

    /**
     * Use Streams when you are dealing with raw data
     * @param data
     */
    private static void writeUsingOutputStream(String data) {
        OutputStream os = null;
        try {
            os = new FileOutputStream(new File("/Users/pankaj/os.txt"));
            os.write(data.getBytes(), 0, data.length());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            try {
                os.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Use Files class from Java 1.7 to write files, internally uses OutputStream
     * @param data
     */
    private static void writeUsingFiles(String data) {
        try {
            Files.write(Paths.get("/Users/pankaj/files.txt"), data.getBytes());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Use BufferedWriter when number of write operations are more
     * It uses internal buffer to reduce real IO operations and saves time
     * @param data
     * @param noOfLines
     */
    private static void writeUsingBufferedWriter(String data, int noOfLines) {
        File file = new File("/Users/pankaj/BufferedWriter.txt");
        FileWriter fr = null;
        BufferedWriter br = null;
        String dataWithNewLine=data+System.getProperty("line.separator");
        try{
            fr = new FileWriter(file);
            br = new BufferedWriter(fr);
            for(int i = noOfLines; i>0; i--){
                br.write(dataWithNewLine);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            try {
                br.close();
                fr.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Use FileWriter when number of write operations are less
     * @param data
     */
    private static void writeUsingFileWriter(String data) {
        File file = new File("/Users/pankaj/FileWriter.txt");
        FileWriter fr = null;
        try {
            fr = new FileWriter(file);
            fr.write(data);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            //close resources
            try {
                fr.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```